# How to loop HTML printing when using a list?

Tags: c#, html, printing

I have a list, which contains paths to html files on my PC. I would like to loop through this list and print them all, in the same order they are in the list.

I tried to loop the code that i have found on msdn.microsoft.com for printing an HTML file.

```
List<string> AllHTMLsToPrint = new List<string>();

//things added to AllHTMLsToPrint list

foreach (string strHTMLToPrint in AllHTMLsToPrint)
{
    PrintHelpPage(strHTMLToPrint);
}

private void PrintHelpPage(string strHTMLToPrint)
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(strHTMLToPrint);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

Comment: "I have a problem with printing HTML files." You forgot to tell us what that problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You have a design problem here. You walk your list of html pages to print. Then you open the page in a browser. When the page is loaded you print it.

BUT...

Loading the page may take longer than 100ms. This is the time after which the browser loads the next page. You should change your code so that the next page will load after the current one has been printed. You may not want to use a loop in this case but an index which you may want to increment after printing.

Should look similar to this (not tested):

```
List<string> AllHTMLsToPrint = new List<string>();
private int index = 0;
PrintHelpPage(AllHTMLsToPrint[index]);


private void PrintHelpPage(string strHTMLToPrint)
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(strHTMLToPrint);

}

private void PrintDocument(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    if (index < AllHTMLsToPrint.Count -1)
    PrintHelpPage(AllHTMLsToPrint[++index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've stated that you have a bunch of local html files.
The loading of local html files may not work by setting the URI. 
You could try setting the DocumentStream instead. strHTMLToPrint must then contain the full/relative path to your local html file.

```
webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentStream = File.OpenRead(strHTMLToPrint);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the exact issue is, but I would put this into a background worker so you don't hold up the main thread.  I'd also move the loop into the document loaded system, that way as soon as it has loaded and printed it will move onto the next.

That said you haven't said what your code isn't doing.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    internal List<string> AllHTMLsToPrint = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void StartPrinting()
    {

        //things added to AllHTMLsToPrint list, please note you may need to add file:/// to the URI list if it is a local file, unless it is compact framework

        // start printing the first item
        BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgw.DoWork += bgw_DoWork;
        bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        /*foreach (string strHTMLToPrint in AllHTMLsToPrint)
        {
            PrintHelpPage(strHTMLToPrint);
        }*/
    }

    void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintHelpPage(AllHTMLsToPrint[0], (BackgroundWorker)sender);
    }

    private void PrintHelpPage(string strHTMLToPrint, BackgroundWorker bgw)
    {
        // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

        // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted += (s, ev) => {
            webBrowserForPrinting.Print();
            webBrowserForPrinting.Dispose();

            // you can add progress reporting here

            // remove the first element and see if we have to do it all again
            AllHTMLsToPrint.RemoveAt(0);
            if (AllHTMLsToPrint.Count > 0)
                PrintHelpPage(AllHTMLsToPrint[0], bgw);
        };


        // Set the Url property to load the document.
        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(strHTMLToPrint);
    }

}
```